# Java - How to list files on mapped network drive?

Tags: java, sharepoint

Im trying to connect to a mapped drive (sharepoint) to make a list of the files that exists.

So, I have this code that works fine on listing the files on my local PC:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Directory path here
    String path = "/"; 

    String files;
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

    for(int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++){
        if(listOfFiles[i].isFile()){
            files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            System.out.println(files);
        }
    }
}
```

When path = "/", it displays all the files on my local drive C:. Now I would like to know if there is a way to adapt this to list the files of a mapped network drive (mapped as Y: for example).

Comment: Try using the the fully qualified name - server_name/location_to_folder, instead of a mapped letter...

Comment: Try `File.listRoots()` and see if if you can find it.

Comment: To access a directory on another server you have to use `\\servername\directorypath`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if your os is windows you can use the **\\Server\shared_folder**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Directory path here
    String path = "\\\\server\\shared_folder"; 

    String files;
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

    for(int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++){
        if(listOfFiles[i].isFile()){
            files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            System.out.println(files);
        }
    }
}
```

Java 8+;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Directoty path here
        String path = "\\\\server\\shared_folder";

        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        //if (listOfFiles != null) { We can use Stream.ofNullable
            Stream.ofNullable(listOfFiles)
                  .filter(File::isFile)
                  .map(File::getName)
                  .forEach(System.out::println);
       // }
    }
}
```